# Simple express server listening but not connecting on any browser

Tags: node.js, express

I just finished on another project using localhost:3000 and it was working fine. I have now decided to start another project(on a different day and my computer has been turned off multiple times since the last project) and I started with a simple express server using the following code.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

For some reason, I keep getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on any browser I try it on. I've checked to make sure the port is open, I've tried using a different port, and I've attempted to completely delete the project and start fresh in a new directory but nothing has worked. I have looked online and the general consensus is to disable the firewall which I have also tried but still nothing.

Are there any ideas as to what could be happening? Is my code incorrect? I grabbed the example from the express docs and I've even tried using the express-generator dependency which also did not work.

EDIT: I fixed it. The solution was very simple. This was happening because I am using remote SSH on VSCode and I simply forgot to port forward the 3000 port I was creating the server on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for an answer to my issue and the edit helped. Same issue for me, I was using remote SSH trying to start a server and forgot to do a Local SSH Port Forward.

Running `ssh -L 1337:localhost:3000 USER@REMOTE_HOST_IP` to SSH into my server then checking http://localhost:1337/ worked.

Source: https://node-security.com/posts/basic-ssh-&-ssh-port-forwarding/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you browser cached `https://` in front of localhost:3000.
You could also try to send a request via curl to `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: So oddly enough, no requests are going through, I keep getting a connection refused error when using postman, but when I go on another computer and connect to http://localhost:3000 it works just fine. I suppose I need to do more snooping into my PC settings since it seems to be an issue with my particular computer.